# Regression curve with lowest combined AIC and BIC is a poor predictor

Tags: regression, predictive-models, goodness-of-fit, aic, bic

For fun, I was trying to make a predictor for how long it would take for George R. R. Martin's *The Winds of Winter* to be released. My "best" model is the one that had the lowest combined AIC and BIC score (summed together). I tried polynomials of degree 0 to something like 50. The best one of this sort was this, which had a degree of 3 or 4:

[image]

Where the y-axis is the days since *A Game of Thrones* was released and the x-axis is the number of books released in the *A Song of Ice and Fire* series. Despite this having the best combined AIC and BIC score, it is a poor predictor, predicting in a way that doesn't make any temporal sense. However, this had the best combined AIC and BIC score (the lowest one). This pointed out to me that my notion that "the best predictor is the one with the lowest combined AIC and BIC score" is flawed. Where have I gone wrong in my thinking, and what kind of scoring criteria would be more appropriate?

Comment: In order to define the likelihood for the AIC you had to assign uncertainties to the Y values. Which values did you use? If those were too small, your criterion will naturally prefer the better fit to the data points

Comment: I'm not aware of this, and have assigned no such uncertainties to my Y values. I just used statsmodels's AIC and BIC score as they're given as methods once the model is fit. There ought not to be any uncertainty with the y values, as the past release dates are certain.

Comment: Then what you are doing is quite meaningless. the library you are using probably has some default value (maybe 1) that in your case is very small compared to the scale of the y data. Try for example to scale y by 1/1000 and see what happens. (Note that the uncertainty does not affect the fit result, but it *does* affect the likelihood, so you can't ignore it if you want to use AIC)

Answer (score 1):

Unpenalized polynomial fits to data are notoriously troublesome, particularly near or beyond the limits of the data. For example, does the shape of your relationship at high x-axis values make sense? See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/226553/28500), for discussion of some better approaches.

Also, it seems that you probably would want to model this in the opposite direction, with `days since "Games of Thrones"` as the predictor on the x axis and the number of books in the series as the outcome on the y axis. The same principle of avoiding unpenalized polynomial fits would still apply.

Comment: So, essentially polynomial fits higher than 3 or 4 unregularized tend to suffer from troublesome behavior at the limits? And regularized cubic splines may be a more robust alternative?

Comment: @sangstar even such low degrees of a polynomial can get you into trouble. Unless there’s a theoretical reason for a particular polynomial, penalization or natural (restricted cubic) splines are safest.